# Is the Euclidean Topology finer or coarser than the Alexandrov Topology on R

Tags: general-topology

> Given a poset ${(X,\leq)}$ and an element $x\in X$ we define the set of "majorants" as $M_x=\{y\in X: x\leq y \}$. Show that the collection of Majorants $B= \{M_x: x\in X \}$ is a Basis for a topology on $X$, such a topology is named Alexandrov Topology on $X$. Consider the Alexandrov topology on the poset $\mathbb{(R,\leq )}$, is it finer or coarser than the Euclidean Topology.

$X$ is partially ordered so for every $x\in X$ there exists some $x_0\in X$ so that $x\leq x_0$ which implies the existence of set of majorants $M_x$ and $M_{x_0}$ which consist of different elements so for every $x$ there exists an element of $B$ that contains $x$. For every $B_1=M_x, B_2=M_{x-1}$ there exists $B_3=M_{x+1}$ such that $B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2 $ since the choice of point is arbitrary this proves that $B$ forms a basis of topology but I've been struggling to see if its coarser or finer than the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{(R,\leq)}$. I think we can say that the collection of open balls forms a Basis of the euclidean topology which would be similar to the collection of majorants described here but I couldn't come up with something definitive so I'd appreciate help.

Comment: It's neither coarser or finer. You therefore need two things: a set that's open in the Alexandrov topology but not the Euclidean toplogy, and one that is open in the Euclidean topology but not the Alexandrov topology. Two hints: 1. Start by searching the bases for these respective topologies, and 2. Can open sets in the Alexandrov topology be bounded?